# How do I create a join which says a field is not equal to X?

Tags: sql, database, join

I have the following database table with information about people, diseases, and drugs:

```
PERSON_T              DISEASE_T               DRUG_T
=========             ==========              ========
PERSON_ID             DISEASE_ID              DRUG_ID
GENDER                PERSON_ID               PERSON_ID
NAME                  DISEASE_START_DATE      DRUG_START_DATE
                      DISEASE_END_DATE        DRUG_END_DATE
```

I want to write a query which finds all people who had disease_id 52 but did not take drug 34.  How do I do that?  I tried the following in MySql:

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.gender, p.name, disease_id, drug_id 
   FROM person_t as p 
   INNER JOIN disease_t on disease_t.person_id = p.person_id 
   RIGHT OUTER JOIN drug_t on drug_t.person_id = p.person_id 
   WHERE disease_id= 52 AND drug_id != 34;
```

This gives me all of the records in which a person did not take drug_id 34 as opposed to the people who did not take drug_id 34.  How would I go about writing the query I want?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For those who don't want to use a subquery:

```
   SELECT p.person_id, p.gender, p.name, disease_id
     FROM PERSON_T p 
     JOIN DISEASE_T d ON d.person_id = p.person_id 
LEFT JOIN DRUG_T dt ON dt.person_id = p.person_id
                   AND dt.drug_id = 34
    WHERE disease_id = 52
      AND dt.person_id IS NULL
```

Comment: @Adam Ruth: In MySQL, [LEFT JOIN/IS NULL is the most efficient/performant against columns that aren't nullable](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/), but it's the [opposite for nullable columns](http://explainextended.com/2010/05/27/left-join-is-null-vs-not-in-vs-not-exists-nullable-columns/)

Answer (score 10):

You can use NOT IN:

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.gender, p.name, disease_id
FROM person_t as p 
INNER JOIN disease_t d on disease_t.person_id = p.person_id 
WHERE disease_id = 52
AND p.person_id NOT IN (SELECT person_id IN drug_t WHERE drug_id = 34)
```

Answer (score 6):

Depending on the optimiser NOT EXISTS may be more efficient than NOT IN. Try them both to see which one works best.

```
SELECT p.person_id, p.gender, p.name, disease_id, drug_id 
   FROM person_t as p 
   INNER JOIN disease_t on disease_t.person_id = p.person_id 
   WHERE disease_id= 52 AND NOT EXISTS (
       SELECT * from drug_T WHERE person_id = person_t.person_id AND drug_id = 34)
```

Comment: +1 for NOT EXISTS - This will almost always yield significantly better performance.

Comment: It would be OK to use NOT EXISTS in SQL Server but he appears to be using MySQL. According to this article: http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/ "That’s why the best way to search for missing values in MySQL  is using a LEFT JOIN / IS NULL or NOT IN rather than NOT EXISTS." No harm in trying it anyway I guess... but probably it will be slower.

Comment: Interesting, so the MySQL optimiser works the other way. MySQL is a strange animal sometimes. Thanks for the link.

Comment: I generally prefer to use "not exists" for future maintainability purposes: It's fairly obvious what you're up to. But when I've compared performance, I generally find that "left join / is null" is somewhat faster.